# Round a float number to the nearest integer divisible by five

Tags: c++, c++11, rounding

I search this everywhere, no solution , i need to round to the nearest 5 integers,
don't know how to formulate this , for example round(0.13) will should return 5  ; here is the pattern logic with value to round first and expected result after rounding ;

```
0.12 => 0
0.99 => 0
1.01 => 0
4.99 => 5
5.45 => 5
7.00 => 5
8.00 => 10
9.10 => 10
14.34 => 15
17.4 => 15
17.5 => 20
37.6 => 40
```

Comment: surely 5 is not the nearest multiple of 5 to 0.12… that would be 0.

Comment: Code it yourself... Get the floor, get the ceil, if any of those if divisible by five you are done, if not, for each one of those increment and decrement up to 5 and check if any of those are divisible by 5, and keep track which is closer. You can make that in the same for loop

Comment: i edited sorry for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
float x = roundf(x / 5) * 5;
```

or, assuming `x >= 0` (and, as **@JamesKanze** noted, `x <= INT_MAX`)

```
int n = (int)(roundf(x / 5) * 5 + 0.5);
```

Comment: Assuming `x >= 0 && x <= INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `5 * floor ((n + 2.5) \ 5)`, where `\` denotes integer division. This is obviously not code, but it should be trivial to translate into any language you like.